# Bad request 400 issue percentage signs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can i prevent or fix 400 bad request if the user is inserting directly in the url multiple percentage signs.

For example search.php?q=40%%%%%%%%%

Comment: if the user is directly entering in the URL and it crashes the page, it's a user problem.

Just as if the user changes example.com/index.php to example.pom/index.php

Comment: @Gerton I think that is the correct answer, no need to delete it ;)

Comment: @Halcyon well I have to hand it to him that it's not actually an answer to his direct question. more trying to say that he shouldn't want to fix everything because it might not be worth it.

Comment: meta: Sometimes the question is bad or formulated in a way that it doesn't have a good answer. I think you explained your answer enough.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that should be a normal 200 OK Response, because the browser urlencodes that to

> search.php?q=40%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25

And the Webserver should urldecode that back to

> search.php?q=40%%%%%%%%%

What Webserver Software are you using? And what OS?
What Message does your Webserver Log say?

Comment: WampServer 2.5 windows 8.1 (localhost)

Comment: I would agree to Gerton and Halcyon and say it's the users fault. I haven't worked with windows for at least 4 years, sorry. You could try to run it with linux+nginx+hhvm, because I'm not getting that error when appending some % signs to my urls.